# May landlords evict tenants for late payment

Tags: halacha, money, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, real-estate

According to Halacha, if there is a contract between a tenant and landlord where the tenant will live in  the property for however long (for example one year) and the payment will be distributed over a different time period (for example every month) can the landlord evict and terminate the contract due to a late payment? So Reuven rents an apartment from Shimon and then in the third month Reuven says he can’t pay that month, can Shimon evict him or must he wait till the year is over but has the right to demand compensation in the future?

Comment: Just to clarify ,is this case purely halachic without any Dina dmalchusa? Additionally, this is specifically talking in a case where the contract does not discuss defaulting on rent,correct?

Comment: http://s589827416.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Decision5a.pdf

Comment: https://www.ou.org/life/torah/evictions_halachic_considerations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Be'er Heitiv in Choshen Mishpat 312:4 brings at the end a case from the Maharit about someone who rents a house for 12 dinarim (dinar per month) ,and the renter is a pauper who cannot pay what he owes or pay for future payments ,then it seems pashut that he can be removed ,since the agreement was to be payed a dinar a month.

Just to point out there are other factors which need to be considered, Dina dmalchusa,standard practice, can he eventually pay and so on ...but just bringing what is discussed .

Text of Be'er Heitev:

[image]